# How to get sum of all Edittexts of Recyclerview items? Getting only items which are visible on screen, not all

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am developing an android application, in which I have Edit texts in adapter rows of Recyclerview. Now I want to get sum of these Edit text values entered by user in activity. I have used below code for this purpose:

```
 int count = listArray.size();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) mRv_products.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(i);
        if (ll != null) {
            Log.v("TAG", "Item considered:" + i);
            EditText t = (EditText) ll.findViewById(R.id.edt_quantity_ship_now);
            String amount = t.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!amount.isEmpty())
                sum += Float.parseFloat(amount);
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, I am getting views only for items which are visible on screen, not all. For example, if I have 10 total items in Recyclerview and only 3 items are visible on screen, I am getting sum of only 3 items which are visible on screen.

So far I have used other options for getting Edit text:

```
mRv_products.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
```

and

```
mRv_products.getChildAt(i);
```

Comment: please post your whole to get answers

Comment: please post your whole answers

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your adapter class create a string Array list.

```
 private ArrayList<String> list;
```

Initialize this list in your adapters constructor and also create its getter setter and then in your onBindViewHolder() method add the editext textchangelistener and in this listeners onchangedtext() method add the following code

```
list.set(position,edittext.getText().toString);
```

Now you can get all the edittext value through the getter then you combine all the values using string builder.

Comment: Thank you, It was helpful. I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do:

1. I will add textWatcher for every editText in RecyclerView item.
2. then will declare a variable in recyclerView Item model
3. when any text changed in editText, store the value in that item model.
4. when sum need to be calculated, iterate the list of model & calculate the result.

Main theme of recyclerView of any adapterView is that your view may or may not exist but your item list always exist. So, always update & use your item list as per as your requirement. It will help you a lot.

Hope it will help you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking about the same. It seems like there is no direct way to get all adapter item views.

Comment: you need to consider always your item list model not the views. check my updated answer

Comment: Ok @Sayem, I agree.